# is it possible to use iPhone 4/5's full native resolution instead of using the half-size coordinates of older iPhones

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

The problem is, Cocos seems to think retina devices are the same resolution as standard devices. If you draw a sprite at 768,1024 on the ipad, it will put it at the upper right corner. If you draw a sprite at 768,1024 on the retina ipad, content scaling makes it so it also puts it in the upper right corner. Yet if you draw a sprite on the retina iphone 5 at 640,1136 it isn't in the upper right corner, its off the screen by 2x the distance. In order to put it in the corner you have to draw it at 320,568 because of the content scaling.

I do have a Default-568h@2x.png image, and I am on version 2.1.

My question is:  Is there a way to get Cocos2d to make it so that drawing a sprite at 640,1136 on an iPhone5 will result in the sprite being in the upper right corner?

Is it possible to set up a cocos2d custom GL projection and set winSizeInPoints to equal winSizeInPixels and content scale 1.0 so that you can use the iPhone 4/5's full native resolution instead of using the half-size coordinates of older iPhones.

Comment: have you tried not enabling retina display, i.e. calling: `[director enableRetinaDisplay:NO]` when setting up your CCDirector?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this by [changing the iPad suffix](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest_2.x/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_file_utils.html#a2b0768327fc72df80099f661c5606f8b) to use "-hd" via CCFileUtils. That way iPad devices will load the regular -hd assets for Retina iPhones.

Update regarding comments:

The positions on devices is measured in points, not pixels. So a non-retina iPad and a retina iPad both have a point resolution of 1024x768. This is great exactly because it makes adapting to screens with different pixel densities a no-brainer. This also works on the iPhone devices.

My suspicion is that you simply haven't added the Default-568h@2x.png launch image to your project yet, which may cause the widescreen devices to be treated differently.

And specifically on older cocos2d versions dated before iPhone 5 there's a bug that will treat the iPhone 5 as a non-Retina device, proper default image or not.

Comment: The problem is, Cocos seems to think retina devices are the same resolution as standard devices.  If you draw a sprite at 768,1024 on the ipad, it will put it at the upper right corner. if you draw a sprite at 768,1024 on the retina ipad, content scaling makes it so it also puts it in the upper right corner.  Yet if you draw a sprite on the retina iphone 5 at 640,1136 it isn't in the upper right corner, its off the screen by 2x the distance.  In order to put it in the corner you have to draw it at 320,568 because of the content scaling.

Comment: in standard mode winSizeInPoints == winSizeInPixels. In retina mode it doesnt...  So I need a way to set the cocos projection to make it treat a retina screen as a standard screen that is x2 the size, so it is close to matching the ipad resolution.  Is this possible?

Comment: So you are saying that you can draw a sprite at 640,1136 and view it on an iPhone5 and it will be in the upper right corner for you?

Comment: it really should be, of course you must consider that the sprite's texture is anchored at the center by default so in that case you'd see only the lower left quarter of the sprite's texture

Comment: can you try it and let me know your results and what I can do to resolve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can share, easy way to do this is put all common sprite in sprite sheet and in runtime check if iPad, if yes then load iPhone HD sheet. We did this in many project and worked.

```
if(IS_IPAD)
{
   [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"GameSpriteSheet-hd.plist"];
}
else 
{
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"GameSpriteSheet.plist"];

}
```

For background image, good to have separate iPad image, if scaling not look bad then you can scale image at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand what you are trying to do, the following approach should work:

1. call `[director enableRetinaDisplay:NO]` when setting up your `CCDirector`;
2. hack or override the following methods in `CCDirector`'s so that winSizeInPixels is defines as the full screen resolution:

   a. `setContentScaleFactor:`;

   b. `reshapeProjection:`;

   c. `setView:`;

Step 1 will make sure that no scaling factor is ever applied when rendering sprites or doing calculations; Step 2 will ensure that the full screen resolution is used whenever required (e.g., when defining the projection, but likely elsewhere as well).

About Step 2, you will notice that all listed methods show a statement like this:

```
winSizeInPixels_ = CGSizeMake( winSizeInPoints_.width * __ccContentScaleFactor, winSizeInPoints_.height * __ccContentScaleFactor );
```

`__ccContentScaleFactor` is made equal to `1` by step 1, and you should leave it like that; you could, e.g. customise winSizeInPixels calculation to your aim, like this:

```
if (<IPHONE_4INCHES>)
    winSizeInPixels_ = CGSizeMake( winSizeInPoints_.width * 2, winSizeInPoints_.height * 2 );
else 
    winSizeInPixels_ = CGSizeMake( winSizeInPoints_.width * __ccContentScaleFactor, winSizeInPoints_.height * __ccContentScaleFactor );
```

Defining a custom projection would unfortunately not work because winSizeInPixels is always calculated based on `__ccContentScaleFactor`; but, `__ccContentScaleFactor` is also used everywhere in Cocos2D to position/size sprites and the likes.

A final note on implementation, you could hack this changes into the existing `CCDirectorIOS` class or you could derive from it your own `MYCCDirectorIOS` and override the methods there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @patrick: did you have any success with the approach I suggested?